# bad interpreter: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pip, macos-big-sur

I get the following error when trying to upgrade pip:

zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory

Yet, I have uninstalled Xcode-Beta and I cannot find it in the Developer or Application folders.

I have a recent, working version of Xcode in my Application folder.

Answer (score 0):

The script `/usr/local/bin/pip` has [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3` and there is no such file.

Edit `/usr/local/bin/pip` and change the path to an existing interpreter. Or remove the file altogether and reinstall `pip` using an existing interpreter.